# Run my app when a file with custom extension is selected (and return path of file)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wrote an Xamarin android app. I want that when users clicked on (dat) and (pdfl) files my application runs and then i can use selected file address to open it.

```
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionEdit,
                        Intent.ActionGetContent, Intent.ActionSendto },
                    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault,
                                         Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryOpenable },
                    DataPathPatterns = new[] { @".*\\.dat", @".*\\.pdfl" },
    DataMimeTypes = new[] { "*/*", "*/*" },
    DataHosts = new[] { "*", "*" },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "content", "file" })]
```

with this code my app loads when (dat) and (pdfl) files selected. but i cant get that file address as an argument. i used
Address= Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
before this on windows version

Comment: please [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+get+file+path+from+intentfilter+site:stackoverflow.com) before posting

Comment: Jason i did it for 6 hours, but i didn't find my answer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.intent.data?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13

Comment: i found it             
            string action = Intent.Action;
            string type = Intent.Type;



            if (Intent.ActionView.Equals(action) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            {
                Android.Net.Uri fileUri = Intent.Data;
                filecontent = fileUri.Path;
                
                
            }

Comment: https://thatcsharpguy.github.io/post/opening-files-xamarin-forms/

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can post it as an answer and then [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.

Comment: i cant do it, im banned

Comment: i have another problem now, bufferstream says u cant access the file. because of android 11 policies. what can i do now? there is no access prompt when i want to buffer that.
maybe i should copy that file in cache folder. huh?